# What are keys and how do I use them?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsurl

I'm working on an iCloud compatible app and I am researching how to detect whether a file is being uploaded/downloaded or has completed that. **I found that this can be detected with NSURL "keys,"** such as `NSURLUbiquitousItemIsDownloadingKey` or `NSURLUbiquitousItemIsUploadingKey`. I'm still working on learning about programming, so what are these keys? How can I use them to detect the status of the files (I want the app to know when a file is done uploading to iCloud or done downloading (whichever side the device is on)).

I read that I can use `resourceValuesForKeys:error:` to query the state of these keys, so would I put this into an IF statement and see if the result is expected, such as "yes" or "no"? Thanks for your help.

```
if ([destination resourceValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLUbiquitousItemIsUploadingKey] error:NULL]) {

    //is uploading??

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed code looks almost workable, but for one thing: `resourceValuesForKeys:error:` returns a dictionary whose keys are the same as the constants you pass in and whose values are as specified in [the documentation for those keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW154). In the case of `NSURLUbiquitousItemIsUploadingKey`, the value is an `NSNumber` instance wrapping a `BOOL` value.

So... assuming `destination` is an `NSURL` pointing to an item in your ubiquity container:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLUbiquitousItemIsUploadingKey];
NSDictionary *values = [destination resourceValuesForKeys:keys error:&error];
if (values == nil)
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
else if ([[values objectForKey:NSURLUbiquitousItemIsUploadingKey] boolValue])
    NSLog(@"uploading");
else
    NSLog(@"not uploading");
```

If you're only querying one key, you can use [`getResourceValue:forKey:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/getResourceValue%3aforKey%3aerror%3a) to be a little more concise.